# Converting error with binding on dependency property

Tags: c#, xaml, binding, winrt-xaml, dependency-properties

I have an `abstract class MyParentClass`. I have a generic class that inherits from `MyParentClass` named `MyChildClass<T>`.

I have a `UserControl` named MyControl with a MyDP dependency property.

In my view model, I have a `MyParentClass` property named MyProperty. I initialize MyProperty to a new instance of `MyChildClass<string>`.

In my view, I have this code : `<MyControl MyDP={Binding MyProperty} />`

And binding fails with this message (in console output):

> Error: Converter failed to convert value of type
>   'MyChildClass`1[[System.String]]' to type 'MyParentClass';
>   BindingExpression: Path='MyProperty' DataItem='MyViewModel'; target
>   element is 'MyControl'; target property is 'MyDP' (type
>   'MyParentClass').

I don't understand how the conversion could somehow fail, since `MyChildClass<T>` inherits from `MyParentClass`. (I have no conversion problem anywhere else).

However, if I change my dependency property type from `MyParentClass` to `object`, the binding works.

Comment: See [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/5e42e6a1-740f-48b2-9908-09a474f9d413/error-converter-failed-to-convert-value-of-type-when-type-is-derived?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Comment: Thanks. That could resolve my problem... if my child class what not generic ! When I create a SubChildClass with a specific type and integrate it in a XAMPL page, this works if MyProperty has the same generic type.

At least now I understand the problem. Thanks again.